# External IP column is empty in the kubectl get services result set

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, kubernetes

I have created the service with the following config file:

```
{
   "kind":"Service",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{
      "name":"my-service",
      "labels":{
         "app":"my-service"
      }
   },
   "spec":{
      "ports": [
         {
           "port":8080,
           "targetPort":"http-server"
         }
      ],
      "selector":{
         "app":"my-service"
      },
      "type": "LoadBalancer"
   }
}
```

Executed the following command:

```
$ kubectl create -f my-service.json

            service "my-service" created
```

Then I want to see the external address of the service:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME             CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
my-service   10.0.203.169                 8080/TCP   3m
kubernetes       10.0.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    32m
```

In the examples of kubernetes apps it says there should be an "External IP" column, which is set:

```
$ kubectl get services
NAME              CLUSTER_IP       EXTERNAL_IP       PORT(S)       SELECTOR               AGE
guestbook         10.0.217.218     146.148.81.8      3000/TCP      app=guestbook          1h
redis-master      10.0.136.3       <none>            6379/TCP      app=redis,role=master  1h
redis-slave       10.0.21.92       <none>            6379/TCP      app-redis,role=slave   1h
...
```

kubectl events shows no information about the load balancer and service.

What might be the problem?

I am using AWS if it helps.

Btw. If I look at the AWS console I can see the DNS name of the Load Balancer and connect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your output doesn't look like the example output, then you are most likely using an older version of `kubectl` (the human friendly output changes over time to become more human friendly). Check your version of `kubectl` and grab a newer one if it isn't up to date (1.2.0 or newer).

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.2", GitCommit:"528f879e7d3790ea4287687ef0ab3f2a01cc2718", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It can take a few minutes for the external IP to show up because it takes a while for the cloud provider (EC2 in this case) to provision a load balancer for you.

On the off chance that it doesn't show up after a few minutes, run `kubectl get events` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question with new information. External IP column shows up but with nothing in it. Looked into AWS console and there is a Load Balancer created

Comment: I can get the dns name of the Load Balancer from the AWS console, but not from the External IP column